# zero length variable added to for iteration not working

Tags: bash, environment-variables

The question is simple . I have the following script in bash :

```
#!/bin/bash

a=`echo " 1 2 3 hello " | egrep -o "1"`
b=`echo " 1 2 3 hello " | egrep -o "2"`
c=`echo " 1 2 3 hello " | egrep -o "4"`

echo $a
echo $b
echo $c
echo "--"

echo "first print : "

if [ -z $c ]; then echo "zero length"; fi # condition met

echo "second print : "

for i in $a $b $c; do

if [ -z $i ]; then echo "zero length" # does not recognize variable $c , no print

fi
done
```

There are 3 variables, a, b and c. c is the only one that is empty, it has length zero of string inside. The first "if" proves this, however, when i try to add the variables to a "for" iteration, the condition is not recognized. How can i make this work ? I need to do this, since i have very many variables that need tested in a single loop, and not use a single "if" for each and every one of them .
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always quote your variable expansions<sup>1</sup>:

```
if [ -z "$c" ]; then echo "zero length"; fi 

echo "second print : "

for i in "$a" "$b" "$c"; do

if [ -z "$i" ]; then echo "zero length"

fi

done
```

When `$c` is empty, then `$a $b $c` is a list of only two items, and so only two iterations are performed. You can see this by running with `set -x`. In your original version:

```
second print :
++ for i in $a $b $c
++ '[' -z 1 ']'
++ for i in $a $b $c
++ '[' -z 2 ']'
```

whereas with the properly quoted version:

```
second print :
++ for i in "$a" "$b" "$c"
++ '[' -z 1 ']'
++ for i in "$a" "$b" "$c"
++ '[' -z 2 ']'
++ for i in "$a" "$b" "$c"
++ '[' -z '' ']'
++ echo 'zero length'
zero length
```

---

1. There are a few exceptions - see for example [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Comment: yes, thank you so much!!